# Multiple sitemap setup for TYPO3 with dd_googlesitemap

Tags: typo3, xml-sitemap

I am trying to create a multiple sitemap setup for TYPO3 6.2 with the dd_googlesitemap extension, but from reading the docs I cannot figure out if this is doable with the extension itself.

Namely, I have two top-level domains with one codebase, e.g. example.com and example.org. If I create the basic sitemap I will get the content of both domains (because of using the same codebase/database). I want the sitemap to be scoped by the website domain, so that I can have `example.com/sitemap_com.xml and example.org/sitemap_org.xml`.

Has someone stumbled upon this issue before and knows if it's possible with dd_googlesitemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, dd_googlesitemap works like this by default. When triggering the different domain it will initialize the correct root page ID in the Generator class. So, by opening `example.com/sitemap.xml` you get all the pages under the `example.com` domain, and `example.org/sitemap.xml` will give you all pages under `example.org`.

Another point is that you can as well initialize the root page ID yourself if you want to, by adding id=xxx to the URL, such as `example.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap&id=xxx`.